# How do I recover a Diablo III account without my cell phone?

Tags: diablo-iii

A little while ago, my cell phone was stolen. Two days ago, I formatted my hdd and backed up my Diablo III folder. However, when I tried to log in, I was told that my account has been locked for suspicious activity.

Then, when I tried to reset my password through the [password reset form](https://us.battle.net/account/support/password-reset.html), I noticed that the code is sent by SMS, and I don't even have the cell phone, never mind that number.

Finally, I found the [account recovery form](https://us.battle.net/account/support/account-recovery.html). I thought it would be fine, but then I saw a video and saw that they request a photo from our identity card! I bought Diablo III using a false last name; only my first name is real. So, I completed the form and sent an image of the error saying that the account has been locked. I've tried to submit a ticket but you can't without login.

What can I do to get my account unlocked?

Comment: Looks like you've short yourself in the foot on your own.  Not sure we can help you with bypassing Blizzard's security.

Comment: I would first contact my phone operator and ask for the recovery of the Sim Card(and the same number) Don't know on yours but on mine its 7 euros and only need some details to prove you are the rightful owner of the number(Done on more than once, on diferent operators and usually they give you the sim card on the same day). Even if you don't have a cellphone ask a friends and use "your" number to prove blizzard that the account is yours.

Comment: I quit Blizzard a long time ago, but didn't they change their EULA to require your *real* name when making an account? If so, you're in violation by default and you'd wind up banned even if you regain control of the account...

Answer (score 3):

Your only solution in this instance will be to contact Blizzard support via phone - they will need to verify who you are and then they'll be able to update these details on your account so you can regain access.

From the best I can make out of [this blue post via MMO-Champion](http://blue.mmo-champion.com/topic/90045-telefono-blizzard-latino-/) the contact details you need to use will be one of the following;

Contact Phone - 1 (800) 592-5499

- International: (949) 955-0283
- From Chile: 1230-020-5554
- From Mexico: 001-888-578-7628
- From Argentina: 0800-333-0778

Support is open Monday to Friday, 8am to 8pm PST

Comment: You can give this a try, but Blizzard has a fairly strict policy. If they don't get proof that you are the person that bought the account, you won't gain access. Believe me, I tried, I had a false name on my first battle.net account as well.

Comment: I buyed Diablo III from a service named here  as RapidPago, login in you blizzard account, print a invoice then go to the local and paid, so i still have that invoice is generated by this paid system(rapidpago) but its clearly saying depositing in argentinian cash to one of the blizzard account.I will try to phone them

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with no longer having access to my cell number, but had purchased Starcraft 2 physically, so I had the physical cd-key for it.  This is an acceptable secondary form of ID, so I created a second battle.net account and sent in a ticket from it.  Support was able to remove the sms verification on my real account, and unlock it for me.

So, you can always create a second battle.net account to discuss your first one, and if you have a physical cd-key for another game on the account, you can use it to regain access.

Comment: I didn't buyed diablo III physically, so i don't have the cd-key, thanks anyway